# PHP delete file from mapped network drive

Tags: php, file-io, network-drive

I have mapped a network drive and tested - copy file from local server to mapped drive is working. But when I want to delete the uploaded file (using`unlink()`). There is an error: `"cant open stream, no such file.."`

Copy Script:

```
copy('local_path', "\\\\serverName\\mappedFolder\\subFolder\\test.txt");
```

Remove Script:

```
unlink("\\\\serverName\\mappedFolder\\subFolder\\test.txt");
```

Why does the upload work okay but the deletion is not?

Comment: whats the error log say?

Comment: Error msg:
Warning: unlink(\\serverName\mappedFolder\subFolder\test.txt): No such file or directory in D:\LocalServer\programFolder\delete.php on line 288

Comment: are the values for `serverName`,`mappedFolder`,and `subFolder` called on the remove script page like they are on the copy script page?

Comment: Yes, the path are same

Comment: Finally, the deletion get work by the following code: 
if(is_dir("\\\\serverName\\mappedFolder")){
   if($a = opendir("\\\\serverName\\mappedFolder\\subFolder")){
       unlink("\\\\serverName\\mappedFolder\\subFolder\\test.txt");
       closedir($a);
   }
}

But I still get no idea why it works...